# How can I change the keyboard layout in XP mode?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout, windows-xp-mode

I'm running the Japanese windows XP mode in an English Windows 7, and because the Japanese XP Mode is interpreting my (US) keyboard's scancodes as a Japanese keyboard. For example, if I type `"` I get `*` in the VM. How can I change the scancode mappings to match a US keyboard, while still being able to type Japanese?

Please note that the language bar does not help - I want to be able to use it in the Japanese IME, but with the American scancode mappings. Changing over to the US keyboard IME would leave me unable to type Japanese (although then the scancodes do line up properly). Since XP can handle US keyboard scancode mappings with a Japanese IME on an English edition of Windows, it should be able to handle it in a Japanese edition as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can install more than one keyboard. If you go to `Control Panel - Languages` you can add a new keyboard in English. To switch between the keyboards, it is as simple as clicking on the IME bar with the mouse and switch between English and Japanese. You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I switch between English and Japanese keyboard all the time, and I am actually using a Spanish keyboard.

がんばって！

Comment: This doesn't quite help - I can type punctuation in English then, fine, but I can't type punctuation in the Japanese keyboard (so, eg, 「」・ won't work) and it's a pita to swap language modes just to type things like quotes or backslashes.